# How can I reach NaN values in my dataframe with a single condition?

Tags: python, pandas

in my dataframe, I want to select the rows for which `image_text` is neither an empty string nor a NaN value. When I said `df.dropna(subset = ['image_text'], inplace= True)` I can reach NaN values so it works. Non of these 3 commands work:

1. `df[(df.image_text!='')|(df['image_text'].notna())]`
2. `df[(df.image_text!='')|(math.isnan(df['image_text'])==False)]`
3. `df[(df.image_text!='')|(np.isnan(df['image_text'])==False)]`

I would like to add another condition after or and reach NaN values. So that I can do the whole filtering in a single command. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: `df[df['image_text'].fillna('').ne('')]` or `df[df['image_text'].notna() & df['image_text'].ne('')]`

Comment: ```df[df['image_text'].notna()]``` didnt work out to reach NaN values. Also cant fill NaNs with ```df[df['image_text'].fillna('').ne('')]```

Comment: Then they might not be real NaNs, maybe strings?

Comment: when I check their type, it says float but with ```df.dropna(subset = ['image_text'], inplace= True) ``` somehow i am able to filter them.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your input, without it it's unfortunately only speculations